Disable tooltip "collapse range"
How do you disable the tooltip on the side that says "Click to collapse the range". It frequently gets in the way when I'm trying to collapse multiple indentions.
And no, editor.hover.enabled : false does not seem to affect the collpase/exapnd buttons.
Screenshot
There are settings that affect the arrow buttons themselves. For instance:
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always"
So is there any setting that changes the behaviour the the pop up that reads "Click to collapse the range"?

That's not a tooltip. This is what a tooltip look like https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.gamedev.tv%2Ft%2Fhow-do-i-get-these-tooltips-to-show-up-in-visual-studio-code%2F182394&psig=AOvVaw3SaI7lA1AomJw6x10GkpX6&ust=1721835273719000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCPD6rK6-vYcDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE

Well, what is it then?

Normally it suppose to appear when you hover over Down-arrows like icon next to rule numbers.

Yes, I know... I want it to not appear as I find it disruptive when I collapse one field and then try to read next line only for this popup to block it.

Keep away Cursor from Down-arrows. Other than that i don't know how to fix it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
